# Validar que input sea formato fecha

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario, con un input que se llama Fecha Nacimiento y es de formato date, lo que necesito es validar del lado del servidor, mediante php que ese input sea una fecha.

por ejemplo, asi valide que el nombre sea obligatorio:

```
if (trim($nombre)==""){
    $errores['nombre'] = "¡El nombre es obligatorio!";
    $error = true;
    }
```

como seria en ese caso para validar la fecha? gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo una validación de tu forma, sería:

```
$fecha_valida = strtotime($variable_fecha) ? true : false;
if (!$fecha_valida){
    $errores['fecha'] = "¡La fecha no es válida!";
    $error = true;
    }
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función `checkdate` que recibe como parametro el mes, dia y año, suponiendo que lo obtienes por `POST`

```
$myDate = $_POST['fecha'];
$date_arr = explode('-', $myDate); //separamos la fecha que va separada por -
if (checkdate($date_arr[0], $date_arr[1], $date_arr[2])) {
        $errores['fecha'] = "Fecha  no válida";
         $error = true;
  }
```

tomado de [Documentacion PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)